# facing issue dealing with collections in jaxb moxy unmarshalling due to getter method getting invoked twice

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, unmarshalling, moxy

I am using jaxb moxy unmarshalling, and my java object has some logic in getter methods to set values in Array. so facing issue in unmarshalling, as the getter method is invoked twice by jaxb framework while unmarshalling. is there any way to avoid this getter method being called twice? can some thing be set in binding xml to avoid this getter call for null check?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify `@XmlAcessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` so that MOXy (or and JAXB implementation) uses the field directly instead of the property (get/set methods).  With this access type you will want to put the annotations on the fields.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html